# Set blurred image background in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uicolor

I have an image as background of an ios app.

I want to make that image blurred using the iOS7 blur effect.

How can I achieve that? Minimum iOS version support of my iOS app is 6.0.

Comment: You suppose to use UIImageView to display your image and set UIImageView's alpha value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image will be in a `UIImageView`.

You can use this code...

```
self.theImageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

just set the alpha to whatever you want.

**EDIT**

From the comments you are actually looking for the iOS 7 blur effect.

This is very different from setting transparency.

What you are looking for is the category available from here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=wwdc_2013/wwdc_2013_sample_code/ios_uiimageeffects.zip

You will need to download the category then when you set the background just blur the image before putting it into the background pattern.

Comment: can i set the image via code like this :self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"register_form_bg"]].... 
and then assign alpha to it. As my images are dynamic and changes based on user.

Comment: OK, so what do you think setting transparency will do? If it is the background then there is nothing to come through it.

Comment: Actually, The user will upload his image.The background image will be of the user that is logged in. I want to make that image as translucent.

Comment: @DhruvJindal What I meant was. If you set transparency on the background then there is nothing behind it to show through. I imagine all you will get is either black or white showing through the image so it will just fade. What effect are you trying to achieve? There may be a different way to do it.

Comment: i want to create the blur effect that is new in ios 7.

Comment: Ah, transparency is very different from blur. What you need is the image effects category. I'll find the link...

Answer (score 2):

There is difference between transperency and translucency.
You can adjust transperency by using 'alpha' property as mentioned by fogmeister.
This will give you somewhat similar results.

AFAIK there is no direct API to apply translucency effect on image. Alternatively You can alter the image in external image editor tool eaisily and use it in your application.

Note : For image to have translucent effect, you need to have another image/text behind it.

Answer (score 2):

set your imageView alpha value t 0.4 to 0.6

or

if you want dynamic blurred image background like below

[image]

[FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)

Comment: I think imageview's alpha value is between 0 to 1 in xcode

Answer (score -1):

Simple Process:

1. Use a png file as background image.
2. Set this image's transparency level using photoshop.

Comment: The background image is dynamic. It is the image of the logged in user. So I cannot use photoshop in this case.